# PHP to read a string from socket

Tags: php

I bind with a socket as follows:

```
<?
// set some variables
$host = "x.x.x.x";
$port = 1234;
// don't timeout!
set_time_limit(0);
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create
socket\n");
// bind socket to port
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to
socket\n");
?>
```

Now how do I read strings coming from the socket and store it in a variable? 
The socket has collection of strings in the following format:
12;3p6;4p

where p is the terminating character for each set of a;b values
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You should use

> socket_read()

to read the incoming data from the socket. Here is a nice tutorial on the socket programming in php.

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Socket-Programming-With-PHP/

On a sidenote, PHP is not a very suitable language for socket programming and use it only if its absolutely necessary.

Comment: will socket_read also help me to read a live stream data from socket server? Thanks